# Sort Dictionary which contains list of dictionaries by value

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I've got a dictionary of the following format:

```
{"key1": [{"title":"bla bla", "percentage": "0.3493"},{"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage":"0.293"}],
"key2": [{"title":"bla bla", "percentage": "0.635"},{"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage":"0.987"}]}
```

So basically it is a dictionary which contains lists of dictionaries as values.

I want to sort this in descending order by the percentage field - so with the above example I would like to obtain:

```
{"key1": [{"title":"bla bla", "percentage": "0.3493"},{"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage":"0.293"}],
"key2": [{"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage": "0.987"},{"title":"bla bla", "percentage":"0.635"}]}
```

I would also like to obtain a global view of the highest percentages. For example:

1. "key2" : {"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage": "0.987"}
2. "key2" : {"title":"bla bla", "percentage": "0.635"}
3. "key1" : {"title":"bla bla", "percentage": "0.3493"}
4. "key1" : {"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage":"0.293"}

I've looked into various ways of sorting in Python, but I'm still not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We sort the list of values for each key in the dictionary on the value for key `percentage` in descending order, and then we use dictionary comprehension to recreate the dictionary

```
dct = {"key1": [{"title":"bla bla", "percentage": "0.3493"},{"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage":"0.293"}],
"key2": [{"title":"bla bla", "percentage": "0.635"},{"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage":"0.987"}]}

result = {key: sorted(value, key=lambda x:x['percentage'], reverse=True) for key, value in dct.items()}
print(result)
```

The output will be

```
{'key1': [{'title': 'bla bla', 'percentage': '0.3493'}, 
{'title': 'bla bla bla', 'percentage': '0.293'}], 
'key2': [{'title': 'bla bla bla', 'percentage': '0.987'}, 
{'title': 'bla bla', 'percentage': '0.635'}]}
```

For the global view, we first update the inner dictionaries so we have the `key` attribute present there.
We then create the overall list of values (global view) by merging all list of values, and then sorting them on percentage in a descending order

```
dct = {"key1": [{"title":"bla bla", "percentage": "0.3493"},{"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage":"0.293"}],
"key2": [{"title":"bla bla", "percentage": "0.635"},{"title":"bla bla bla", "percentage":"0.987"}]}

#Update inner dictionaries with the name of the key for each dictionary
for key, value in dct.items():
    for v in value:
        v.update({'key':key})

global_view = sorted([v for value in dct.values() for v in value], key=lambda x:x['percentage'], reverse=True)

print(global_view)
```

The output here will be

```
[
{'title': 'bla bla bla', 'percentage': '0.987', 'key': 'key2'}, 
{'title': 'bla bla', 'percentage': '0.635', 'key': 'key2'}, 
{'title': 'bla bla', 'percentage': '0.3493', 'key': 'key1'}, 
{'title': 'bla bla bla', 'percentage': '0.293', 'key': 'key1'}
]
```